# How would I list assets from a specific subfolder?

Tags: assets, forloop, image

In the case that I have an asset folder structure like this:

```
/images
   /group-a
   /group-b
   /group-c
```

How would I loop through all of the images in `/group-b` without having to assign them to entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`folderId`-parameter](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.assets#folderId) in [`craft.assets`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.assets):

```twig
{% for image in craft.assets.folderId(1) %}
    <li><img src="{{ image.getUrl('thumb') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

You can get the `folderId` by inspecting the folder-name in the CP.

Comment: Is there also a possibility to this recursively? Getting all files from the subfolder and its subfolders.